# Commenting out code blocks in Atom

Tags: atom-editor

I have been moving from Webstorm and RubyMine to Atom and I really miss a feature from the Jetbrains editors where you select a code block and press <kbd>CMD</kbd> + <kbd>-</kbd> and it adds language specific comment character(s) to the beginning of each line. (`#` for ruby. `//` for js, `/*` for css etc.).

Is there a built in shortcut for Atom or a package which provides this feature?

Comment: Someone should have also said how to uncomment a block...

Comment: @JimmyR. - If you repeat the command from the accepted answer (ctrl+/) it will uncomment. Although how well it works seems to depend on the type of file and whether you're working in an already commented block or not.

Answer (score 392, accepted):

According to [this](https://bugsnag.com/blog/atom-editor-cheat-sheet), <kbd>cmd</kbd> + <kbd>/</kbd> should do it.

And for Windows and Linux, it is <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>/</kbd>.

Comment: I had to do `cmd + shift + 7` since my swedish keyboard does not have a `/` key like EN keyboards do.

Comment: this is not a block comment, this is a line comment

Comment: Ubuntu + italian keyboard user here - my "/" is on "7" key but `ctrl + shift + 7` doesn't work. Any clue?

Comment: @davideghz on italian keyboards the shortcut is ctrl+ù

Comment: Yes in Windows its ctrl+/ to toggle comment and uncomment.
I  have seen with other editors usually comment is ctrl+/ and uncomment is ctrl+\ . Its cool with atom single key combination to toggle with commenting

Comment: Usually Ctrl+nextToEnter. On Ubuntu+Spanish keyboard: Ctrl+ç but Ctrl+Shift+7 works too.

Comment: Note, this is also how you uncomment a line. Don't be like me and waste 15 mins of your life trying to figure that shit out.

Comment: ctrl + / on Linux Atom

Comment: @AlexanderMills Ironically, it tends to be more reliable to comment-out multiple lines of code with "line comments."  e.g. the `/*` syntax in JavaScript can be unexpectedly terminated by a description of code inside the comment including the characters "*/".  Not uncommon for a comment with a regular expression inside it.

Comment: @AlexanderMills The OP requested line comments.

Comment: @davideghz on my Italian keyboard (on Linux) it works both the way.. either `ctrl + shift + /` or `ctrl + ù`

Comment: My Norwegian keyboard also requires `CMD + Shift + 7`; the only issue is that this opens the help search box in the macOS menubar instead of transforming the marked text into a comment block...

Answer (score 38):

Atom does not have a specific comment-block function, but if you select more rows and then use the normal <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>/</kbd> (Windows or Linux) <kbd>cmd</kbd>-<kbd>/</kbd> (Mac), it will comment all the lines.

Comment: @cryptoKTM see the solution by andrez to solve the HTML issue.

Answer (score 21):

<kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>/</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>7</kbd> doesn't work for me (debian + colombian keyboard). 
In my case I changed the Atom keymap.cson file adding the following:

```
'.editor':
  'ctrl-7': 'editor:toggle-line-comments'
```

and now it works!

Comment: This should be the answer. Thanks

Answer (score 16):

Also, there are packages:

- Comment package for atom [(https://atom.io/packages/comment)](https://atom.io/packages/comment)
- Block-comment-lines https://atom.io/packages/block-comment-lines
- Sublime Block Comments

Answer (score 15):

Pressing (Cmd + /) will create a single line comment. i.e. `// Single line comment`

Type (`/**` and press the Tab key) to create a block comment ala

`/**
 * Comment block
 */`

Comment: This only seems to work in certain file types. It doesn't work in typescript but it should.

Answer (score 14):

with all my respect with the comments above, no need to use a package :

```
1) click on Atom 
1.2) then ATL => the menu bar appear 
1.3) File > Settings  => settings appear
1.4) Keybindings > Search keybinding input => fill "comment"
1.5) you will see :
```

[image: keybindings panel in atom editor]

if you want to change the configuration, you just have to parameter your keymap file

Comment: FYI, the settings can be accessed w/the shortcut `ctrl` + `,` on Windows.

I have the same keybindings as in your screenshot and I keep seeing people suggest `ctrl` + `shift` + `/` but it just isn't working for me on Windows 10 / Atom 1.31.0.

The [block-comment](https://atom.io/packages/block-comment) package worked well and is very lightweight.

Answer (score 8):

You can use <kbd>**Ctrl**</kbd> + <kbd>**/**</kbd>. This works for me.

Answer (score 6):

Multi-line comment can be made by selecting the lines and by pressing Ctrl+/ . 
and Now you can have many plugins for comments

1) comment - https://atom.io/packages/comment 
2) block-comment-lines - https://atom.io/packages/block-comment-lines

better one is block-comment try that..

Comment: the `block-comment` package works like a charm, thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Edit your `keymap.cson` file and add

**Windows**

```
'.platform-win32 .editor':
  'ctrl-/': 'editor:toggle-line-comments'
```

**Mac**

```
'.platform-darwin .editor':
  'cmd-/': 'editor:toggle-line-comments'
```

Now just highlight the text you want to comment and hit the keybinding.

Answer (score 4):

You can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>/</kbd> for Windows.

Answer (score 2):

Atom does not have block comment by default, so I would recommend searching for atom packages by "block comment" and install the one suits to you.

I prefer https://atom.io/packages/block-comment because is has the closest keyboard shortcut to line comment and it works as i need it to, meaning it would not comment the whole line but only the selected text.

`line comment: CTRL+/
 block comment: CTRL+SHIFT+/` (with the plugin installed)

Comment: I prefer `UltCombo/atom-sublime-block-comment` that will use the shortcut CTRL + `?` as default, so you have also the original CTRL + `/`

Answer (score 2):

**Possible reason**: watch out for overlapping keybindings. It has happened in my case and deactivated the initial `toggle line comment` binding:

[image]

The Keybindings you can find in the `Edit -> Preferences -> Keybindings` of the application navbar.

**The solution** was overriding binding for `github:toggle-patch-selection-mode`

[image]

Answer (score 1):

On an belgium keyboard asserted on the mac
<kbd>command</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>/</kbd> is the keystroke for commenting out a block.

Answer (score 1):

CTRL+/ on windows, no need to select whole line, Just use key combination on line which you want to comment out.

Answer (score 1):

first select your block of code then
press **cmd + /** for MacOS